# Access Type Declaration Parent Methods

Tags: go

I'm unmarshalling a GET request from a JSON API. Soem of the fields are a Unix timestamp (in ms). For those fields, I wrote a method to handle unmarshalling. For that to work, I needed to create a new local type `Datetime`.

```
type Datetime time.Time

type Response struct {
  Status    string   `json:"status"`
  CreatedAt Datetime `json:"created_at"`
}


// Handles unmarshalling of Time from the API
func (dt *Datetime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var unixTimeMs int64
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &unixTimeMs); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *dt = Datetime(time.Unix(0, unixTimeMs*1000000))
    return nil
}
```

Now that I have this new Response object, I'd like to call `time.Time` methods on the Datetime. I've tried casting the object (i.e. response.CreatedAt.(time.Time)), but that leads to a panic.

How can I call methods like `time.Time#string` on `Datetime`?

Comment: Side note: Go technically does not have casts at all. What `response.CreatedAt.(time.Time)` is, syntactically speaking, is a [*type assertion*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). Anything of the form `x.(type)` is a claim that: (1) `x` is an *interface value* and (2) that value currently holds `(type)` as its *concrete type*.

Comment: Given that casts in C or C++ *cause* a conversion, it seems likely that you were looking for the conversion described in [Cerise Limón's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61718359/1256452).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) the Datetime to `time.Time` to call a `Time` method. Example:

```
fmt.Println(time.Time(dt).String())
```

Another approach is use a struct with an embedded time field:

```
type Datetime struct {
     time.Time
}
```

All `time.Time` methods are promoted to the `Datetime` type. Modify the UnmarshalJSON method to set `dt.Time` instead of `*dt`.